# Django doesn't render variable after a few lines

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2, render

I just don't get it. Somehow django does't want to render tow variables brand_company and brand_concern even if django do it 2 line before.

This is my definition in my views.py:

```
def BrandDetails(request, brand_id):
    brand = Brands.objects.get(id=brand_id)
    brand_name = brand.name
    brand_pic = brand.img
    brand_concern = Concerns.objects.get(id=brand.concern_id).name
    brand_company = Companies.objects.filter(id=brand.company_id)
    brand_fair = brand.fair
    brand_eco = brand.eco

    context = {
        "brand_id": brand.id,
        "brand_name": brand.name,
        "brand_pic": brand.img,
        "brand_company": brand_company,
        "brand_concern": brand_concern,
        "brand_fair": brand_fair,
        "brand_eco": brand_eco,
    }

    return render_to_response("database/details.html", context)
```

an here is my html-snipped:

```
{% extends "database/index.html" %}

{% block details %}
  <div id="DetailsContent">
    <img src="{{brand_pic}}"></img><br>
    Markenname: {{ brand_name }}<br>
    Unternehmen: {{ brand_company }}<br>
    Konzern: {{ brand_concern }}<br>
    Fair: {% if brand_fair > 0 %}Ja{% endif %}Nein<br>
    Öklogisch: {% if brand_eco > 0 %}Ja{% endif %}Nein<br>
    <h3><a href="http://localhost:8000/database/"> Neue Suche? Einfach hier klicken </a></h3>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The result looks like this:

[I market the two empty places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0LYI.png)

I tested the query in the manage.py shell and there it works perfectly. You can also see that the brand.name and the brand.img are shown, also brand.fair and brand.eco (even if the if-statement doesn't work, but that's another problem, but the become displayed).

Maybe the model helps also, this is the model of Brands:

```
class Brands(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    altName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    fair = models.IntegerField()
    eco = models.IntegerField()
    concern = models.ForeignKey("Concerns", null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey("Companies", null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Brands"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Maybe it's because the Company and the Concern fields are ForeignKeys, but that would be strange.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't believe `img` typically has a closed tag. Can you just use `<img src="{{ brand_pic}}" >` instead and then try?

Comment: @MattCremeens - thanks for your comment. It doesn't solved my problem, but I changed it anyway cause you are right, the closed tag is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for why the brand_company is not showing in the template is that,

```
brand_company = Companies.objects.filter(id=brand.company.pk)
```

`brand_company` is a queryset.

So you need to do like this in your template,

```
Unternehmen: {% for company in brand_company %} {{ company }}{% endfor %}<br>
```

Also, change this line,

```
brand_concern = Concerns.objects.get(id=brand.concern.pk).name
```

Why your if statement does not work:

Because, you ended the if statement before the else statement.

It should be like this,

```
{% if brand_eco > 0 %}Ja{% else %}Nein{% endif %}<br>
```

Comment: Yeah .. hows things? @Anthony

Comment: Hey @Fazil Zaid, thanks for your answer. First, I would like to ask you, why you changed .get(id=brand.concern_id) to .get(id=brand.concern.pk). Is it more common to use pk instead of id? Regarding the if statement it that it's like in the python code, there you also don't need to write the "else"-keyword. But even if I correct my code as you say, it's still always pretend like everything is 0, so it always returns "Nein". But as I said, thats another problem. I will tackle it later.

Comment: why you changed .get(id=brand.concern_id) to .get(id=brand.concern.pk). Is it more common to use pk instead of id? =>
I changed it because **brand** object doesn't have a field with name **concern_id** but it has a field **concern** and it has an id, so **brand.concern.pk** or **brand.concern.id** should be written. Also, you didn't specify primary key explicitly.. so concern.pk would automatically fetch id

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer?

Comment:  Sorry! Good point. Okay, now i tried this: brand_concern = Concerns.objects.get(id=brand.concern.pk).name and this also doesn't work.  It's strange. It looks like it doesn't matter what I put into the dictionary of context, it just doesn't transport the information into the page which should become rendered. Also brand_fair and brand_eco doesn't become displayed. When I delete the if statements it should just show a 0 or a 1, but it just shows nothing. Something is really strange here. I will update my questions tonight, cause know I need to go to work for the next 9 h.

Comment: Hey @Fazil, I'm so sorry for wasting your time. The problem was, that I copied the the view-function inside my view.py and forgot to delete the old version.Because of that django rendered over and over again the old version, since the old version of the function came behind the new version.  Damn! That's embarrassing. So know I will try your other advises, regrind the if-statement and so! Thanks a lot! And again, sorry.

Comment: So, then could you please mark the answer as selected?